# Attention dropout, where was it proposed/used first?

Tags: references, dropout, attention

Attention dropout (dropout on the attention weights) is very common for the Transformer model. In the original [Attention is all you need](https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.03762) paper, dropout is mentioned, but not for the attention weights. However, it is already part in the [initial public push of Tensor2Tensor](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensor2tensor/commit/3d9c62f2aca9492db5c22676416974005b9dcbae).

Where was it proposed first? Where was it used first? Was that written down anywhere?

Comment: did you ever find the answer to this? I am trying to track this down too...

Comment: @Joff Unfortunately no...

Answer (score 1):

There are two main Objects to apply the dropout:

1. **Neurons**, is proposed in [Srivastava et al. [2014]](https://www.cs.toronto.edu/%7Ehinton/absps/JMLRdropout.pdf), called **Dropout**, and used in the fully-connected networks
2. **Weights Matrix**, is proposed in [Wan et al. [2013]](https://proceedings.mlr.press/v28/wan13.html), called **DropConnect**, and this is the method used in the Transformer

And there is a paper which focus on the Self-Attention Layer dropout tricks: [DropAttention: A Regularization Method for Fully-Connected Self-Attention Networks](https://arxiv.org/abs/1907.11065)

Comment: If that link goes dead your answer will become valueless. Please edit to include all the relevant details from it in your answer.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/359926)

Comment: It's not the answer. That paper is newer (2019) than the paper I mentioned (2017).

Comment: Now after your change, it's wrong. DropConnect is *not* used in Transformer. DropConnect is on the weights (parameters). However, I asked about dropout on the attention weights.

Comment: Yes, there is no mention on "attention weights" in the `DropConnect` paper, but it is the same mechanisms and methods.
And I recommend you read the `DropAttention` paper, in this paper, the author give you more tricks and this tricks based on the `DropConnect`